# Xcode 13 mac m1 chip google signin build gives building for iOS Simulator,but linking in object file built for iOS

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I use this plugin **@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth**

and I perform all steps one by one in ANDROID is working but when I build for IOS
its open Xcode but when I run the target app it's give me this error

```
in APP_PATH/ios/App/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.
framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDEMMErrorHandler_3a47e13d8ca81b41e9cdb7ef5468004a.o),
building for iOS Simulator,but linking in object file built for iOS, file 
'APP_PATH/ios/App/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn' 
for architecture arm64
```

Comment: open applications right click on xcode click get info and check open in Rosetta and then build.

Comment: I try this way but I got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

you have to add this code to your Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
 end
end
```

After adding this code install pod

```
pod install
```

and add this code in capacitor.config.json

```
"GoogleAuth": {
        "scopes": [
            "profile",
            "email"
        ],
        "serverClientId": "YOUR_API_KEY.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "forceCodeForRefreshToken": true
    }
```

and in Xcode

[image]

after adding your key clean project and run.

and add arm64 in Building Settings and find **Excluded Architecture**

[image]